# Getting row data from Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a web2py app that uses Datatables extensively, but in fairly simple forms. One of the views uses server-side processing to populate a table, and I need to get data from the row when a user clicks on a row of the table. I've used example code from the Datatables site, but can't get it to work.

Here is the Datatables intialization (datatables 1.10):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#parts-list').dataTable({
        searching: true,
        displayLength: 10,
        lengthChange: false,
        paging: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '/init_ss/default/get_data_server_side',
        "language" : {
            zeroRecords: "The search turned up no part"},
        "columnDefs": [
          {
            "data": null,
            "targets": [ 6 ],
            "defaultContent" : "Click on row to add to request for information</a>"
          }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

This works as expected: the table gets constructed properly, with the last column's content being the words "Click on row to add to request for information."

To process a click on a row in the table with an id of "parts-list," I have this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#parts-list').DataTable();

$('#parts-list tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
        alert("retrieved data from selected row");
} );
</script>
```

This is straight from the Datatables website, in the API reference for row(), data(). For me, it doesn't work - I can't see that the function to retrieve the row data ever gets called when I click in any row of the table.

Comment: What version of `datatables` are you using? First snippet looks like prior 1.10 while last looks like 1.10, which introduced changes to the API. The `row().data()` syntax is available since 1.10.

Comment: Thanks for that insight. I thought I'd updated to the latest, but a double-check showed that was not so. Explains another little problem I'd run into, also.

Comment: I updated Datatables to 1.10 and revised the datatables initialization to 1.10 syntax. The effect of the upgrade was to lose all table formatting (even though I updated the .css files also); I can figure that out. But I still cannot get the code to retrieve row data values to work. So...still the same problem.